# Polarform Solution e function

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Just a very small question just to make sure:

I should solve for $$(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}})^{20}$$and I get the solution that $$e^{–\pi}=-1$$ since $cos(\pi)=-1$. However, the sample solution says it’s positive 1.

Could someone explain?

Comment: Do you mean $e^{-i\pi} = -1$?

Comment: @CasimirRönnlöf yes thank you, I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

$(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})^{20}=e^{i 10\pi}=1.$